# What stage is jHipster UAA in as of October 2016?

Tags: jhipster

The documentation mentions that jHipster UAA is in beta stage and is to be "used at your own risk".

What are the plans for UAA and is it stable enough for use in a new application that is expected to be launched in February?

Answer (score 1):

it is still BETA quality as there are only a few feedbacks on wider usage, and we don't hestitate to unBETA such a feature, if we are not definitly sure. But several JH users are already running the UAA setup in production (me as well), and it works quite stable.

IMHO using UAA is more microservice style and production ready than the JWT solution, because of the following aspects:

- it uses OAuth2 as protocoll for authentication and authorization, what makes it interopable with any oauth2 based system quickly
- it decouples the user domain out from gateway into a own service
- it comes with ready 2 use service-to-service communication solutions by a specific feign client implementation, where you can access control service requests in a different configuration then user requests
- it comes with ready 2 use spring security integration testing tools
- it implements parts of spring cloud security, using defaults (mostly)

The documentation to these testing tools is currently a bit outdated, what I fixed with this question [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster.github.io/pull/336).

In my [blog article](http://stytex.de/blog/2016/09/15/jhipster-3-dot-7-secure-service-communication/) I describe the proper usage of `@AuthorizedFeignClients` and the token mock util.